# What symbol is this (sample space)?

Tags: symbols

What is this symbol, pictured below, which is used to denote sample space in probability theory, according to one textbook (UK's A-Level in Statistics from Edexcel).

And how to typeset it in Latex?

[image]

Comment: Calligraphic or script captial `E`. Would `\mathcal{E}` from package `amssymb` or `\mathscr{E}` from `mathrsfs` do the trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}` and `\mathcal{E}` might come closest to the symbol you are after. This font is freely available.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{E} \]
\end{document}
```

However, there is a font `mathpi` which is a commercial font (see the `mathalfa` documentation for more information). This I believe is exactly the same font as in your picture.

[image]

(from page 7 of the `mathalfa` documentation)

Comment: OK, but how do we say it? It isn't a greek letter, so do we just say "E" when we pronounce it? I want to be pedantic and find out what this "E" is. Wikipedia's article for sample space gives three possible symbols (S, Omega and U), of which this "E" is none.

Comment: @Mihael Call it "E" if possible, or "script E" if necessary.

Comment: Looking at the `mathalfa` documentation (`texdoc mathalfa`, page 7) I'd say that the `mathpi` font contains the sought form.

Comment: ... though, I forgot, the `mathpi` fonts are commercial.